# Converting media files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I like to convert 3gp to ogg in rails. I looked into ffmpeg but I like to know the best way to do this. If conversion could run in the background it would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely background task, so it doesn't really care if its rails or some other framework.

You will need Rails app just to upload file and save it. After that you can use any scheduler to run background task. It can be `sidekiq` (which is my best choice when talking about background tasks), or it can be `whenever` (cron helper for rails), or it also can be just `rake` task.

See, you don't need rails to run ffmpeg command explicitly, however i suppose ffmpeg is good choice to convert videos, but you can also take a look at gstreamer. Again, converter should run separately from rails. Your webapp is just to upload file and schedule file convertion.